# How to use getFirstItem() in collection into magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

How to get first item of collection in magento 2

I am trying

```
    $infoColl = $this->_customFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $infoColl->addFieldToFilter('session_id', $id);
    $infoColl->addFieldToFilter('waiting_list', '');
    $infoColl->getFirstItem();
```

but its not working

Comment: If I were to ask you the same thing, what would to say to me?

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: Please, add more your code lines.

Comment: @nevvermind if i know the answer than i will post answer or if i have question about your question than ask it :-)

Comment: Actually, you would probably say "I need more details". I'm not trying to lecture you, but to make you think from **our** point of view. The chances of getting an answer considerably rise if you know how to give details.

Comment: Check the resulting SQL: `var_dump($infoColl->getSelect()->__toString());` and run it separately. Maybe it's empty. Your code look correct to me.

Comment: your code seems correct to me, did you try to call specific data. I mean something like this `$infoColl->getFirstItem()->getName();`

Comment: @MohammadMujassam i am getting specific data thanks..

Comment: Accept answer if it is useful for you.....

Answer (score 17):

Make sure there is data in your collection. The function will return the first item object from your collection and then you can use it directly.

```
 $collection = $this->_customFactory->create()->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('session_id', $id)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('waiting_list', '');

 if($collection->getSize()){
     $data = $collection->getFirstItem();
     $data->getId();
     $data->getName();
 }
```

Comment: If you pull first element of a collection with getFirstItem() you will get a model every time.
You do not have to check if collection has element, you only need to check if the model has Id
This is a quite handy feature, if you have to create an element if not exist: you can save the model creation

Answer (score 3):

You can use like below:

```
$infoColl = $this->_customFactory->create()->getCollection();
$infoColl->addFieldToFilter('session_id', $id);
$infoColl->addFieldToFilter('waiting_list', '');
$infoCollFirstItem = $infoColl->getFirstItem();
$infoCollFirstItemData =  $infoCollFirstItem->getData();
```

And by **`$infoCollFirstItemData`** data array you can use all columns of the first item of the collection.

You can also use **`fetchItem()`** function for fetch items/rows of the collection one by one.

This is a **preferable approach and even faster**, *as I find at below url*:

> http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/blog/magento-blog-56/post/pitfalls-to-avoid-during-magento-development-286

The example code:

```
$customers = $this->_customFactory->create()->getCollection();
$object=$customers->fetchItem(); //for get first Item/row
//for Iterating collections
    while($object=$customers->fetchItem()){
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>Before call `getFirstItem()`, try to load our collection `$infoColl->load()`</del>

**Update:** @ MohammadMujassam comment: We need to get specific data, like: `$infoColl->getFirstItem()->getName();`

Comment: The collection gets loaded automatically when you call `getFirstItem()`.

Comment: @ nevvermind `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php` there is a method `loadByIncrementIdAndStoreId`, it also tries to load collection before `getFirstItem()`. Please, help us to understand about this. Thanks you.

Comment: Understand what exactly? Every call to `getFirstItem()` will call `load()` _for you_. This happens on _every DB collection_. So it's redundant (not wrong) to do `$coll->load(); $coll->getFirstItem();`. So your answer cannot explain the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fetchItem() method instead

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and resolve it by below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();   
$firstItem = $objectManager->create('Mypackage\MyModule\Model\SyncData')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->getFirstItem();
```

Hope It helps